# PHP Login connecting to MySQL database with SHA1

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, sha1

I'm having trouble with a simple login form and accessing the database. For the exercise, I have to create a simple login form, access the database with SHA1 encryption, then access a members area, but whenever I try to login, I get an invalid username/password message.

Am I storing the hashed password correctly? How do I then access it from the database? I've tried numerous times.

I know it's not good practice to hash passwords with SHA1, but this is part of the exercise I've been set, and I can't see where I'm going wrong.

**dbconnect.php**

```
<?php

   $DBhost = "localhost";
   $DBuser = "root";
   $DBpass = "";
   $DBname = "";

   $DBcon = mysqli_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass,$DBname);

   if ($DBcon->connect_errno) {
       die("ERROR : -> ".$DBcon->connect_error);
   }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

    $userName = strip_tags($_POST['userName']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $userName = $DBcon->real_escape_string($userName);
    $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);

    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT userID, userName, password 
    FROM user WHERE userName='$userName'");
    $row=$query->fetch_array();

    $count = $query->num_rows; 

    if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) 
    && $count==1) {
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['userID'];
    header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
     Invalid Username or Password !</div>";
    }
    $DBcon->close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="signin-form">

    <div class="container">


       <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="login-form">

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign In.</h2>

        <?php
        if(isset($msg)){
            echo $msg;
        }
        ?>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="userName" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Username" name="userName" required />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Password" name="password" required />
    </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
         name="btn-login" id="btn-login"> Sign In </button> 

            <a href="register.php" class="btn btn-default" 
        style="float:right;">Sign UP Here</a>

        </div>  


      </form>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {

    $userName = strip_tags($_POST['userName']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $upass = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $userName = $DBcon->real_escape_string($userName);
    $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
    $upass = $DBcon->real_escape_string($upass);

    $hashed_password = sha1($upass); 

    $check_email = $DBcon->query("SELECT email FROM user 
    WHERE email='$email'");
    $count=$check_email->num_rows;

    if ($count==0) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO user(userName,email,password) 
        VALUES('$userName','$email','$hashed_password')";

        if ($DBcon->query($query)) {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                         successfully registered !
                    </div>";
        }else {
            $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                         error while registering !
                    </div>";
        }

    } else {


        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                     sorry email already taken !
                </div>";

    }

    $DBcon->close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Login & Registration System</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="signin-form">

    <div class="container">


       <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="register-form">

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2><hr />

        <?php
        if (isset($msg)) {
            echo $msg;
        }
        ?>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
         placeholder="Username" name="userName" required />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Email address" name="email" required />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Password" name="password" required />
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
            name="btn-signup">Create Account</button> 
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default" 
            style="float:right;">Log In Here</a>
       </div> 

      </form>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE
userID=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
$userRow=$query->fetch_array();
$DBcon->close();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
     header("Location: index.php");
} else if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['userSession']);
    header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="")` for one thing, is a "false positive". That needs to be split into two separate conditions.

Comment: what you had written in your password_verify() function ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- or you could just use `if (!empty($_SESSION['userSession']))`

Comment: Is the exercise to learn php/Mysql or to learn how to ask questions on SO?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encrypt password with `sha1()` before select compare:

```
$password = $DBcon->real_escape_string(sha1($password));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to *assume* `password_very()` is not the issue. One thing it could be 
is your use of `$count = $query->num_rows;`, here is a snippet of the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

> The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or
>   unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets,
>   mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all
>   the rows in the result have been retrieved.